# Como Retornar múltiplos valores em uma função no python?

Tags: python, flask

Estou desenvolvendo uma API em Python FLASK e preciso mostrar o resultado de um `SELECT` que fiz via `SQL ALCHEMY`. Porém quando uso `return` ele apenas volta o primeiro `ROW` do `SELECT`.

O mais engraçado é que com "print" ele exibe todos resultados sem nenhum problema.

Alguém poderia me ajudar nesse mistério?

```
def lista_unidades():
uni = session.query(UnidadesMam).all()
for u in uni:
    return json.dumps({'Unidade': u.nomeUni, 'Endereco': u.enderecoUni, 'Bairro': u.bairroUni, 'Cep': u.cepUni,
                        'Cidade': u.cidadeUni, 'Estado': u.estadoUni, 'Pais': u.paisUni})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso é devido ao `return`, que no primeiro loop é logo invocado e é encerrada/terminada a função onde ele está contido, neste caso a `lista_unidades()`, faça o seguinte:

```
def lista_unidades():
    uni = session.query(UnidadesMam).all()
    dados = []
    for u in uni:
        dados.append({'Unidade': u.nomeUni, 'Endereco': u.enderecoUni, 'Bairro': u.bairroUni, 'Cep': u.cepUni, 'Cidade': u.cidadeUni, 'Estado': u.estadoUni, 'Pais': u.paisUni})
    return json.dumps(dados)
```

Comment: Deu Certo ele volto todos resultados dentro do array dadoss

Comment: Sera que conseguimos fazer sem array rsrsrs ?

Comment: Isso não sei, talvez haja alguma funcionalidade do flask de fazer isso diretamente @YvesRomeiro: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7102754/jsonify-a-sqlalchemy-result-set-in-flask, http://code.runnable.com/UiIDW0LvVMFPAAAM/how-to-return-json-from-flask-for-python